# Does this exist? Create virtual file shares with arbitrary folders

Tags: filesystems, network-share, file-sharing

I'd like to be able to advertise shares to the network that are in some sense virtual, in that they don't correspond directly to physical folders on a filesystem.

The application would be to offer a share based on location, and another based on department, all from the same physical filesystem.

For example:

```
//fileserver/location_share/london/dept1
//fileserver/location_share/london/dept2
//fileserver/location_share/london/dept3
```

or

```
//fileserver/dept_share/dept1/london
//fileserver/dept_share/dept1/paris
//fileserver/dept_share/dept1/berlin
```

To set this up, I'd create a share name and then choose the folders I want to be visible through that share.

I've looked at DFS but I'm not sure if it can do this.

Comment: The syntax of the paths and the mention of DFS suggest this question deals with Windows shares exported from a server that also is running Windows?

Comment: @rackandboneman: The question is about funtionality rather than a specific platform. The forward-slash path format is from Unix but is not central to the question.

Comment: What server, clients, and file-sharing protocol(s) that you intend to use are, indeed, very central to the question.

Comment: @mfinni: the question is about whether there is a file-serving technology that does what I'm asking, regardless of client, server, or network protocol.

Comment: I suppose the question is coming more from an architect point of view - if there is any file server tech that acts like this I'd simply like to know about it, I don't need guidance on setting something up.

Answer (score 2):

DFS is exactly what you want, assuming this is an Active Directory network.
We a have very similar structure in my company.

Comment: Can you expand on how this works with DFS please?

Comment: DFS uses something called namespaces. You can define as many namespaces as you want with the same real path in place.

Comment: AFAIK namespaces contain shares don't they? I suppose if namespaces could contain arbitrary folders that would be what I'm after. Is that the case?

Answer (score 1):

NTFS supports "symbolic links" and "junction points"; the details should be in the documentation for the "mklink" command.

Comment: Can you expand on how this addresses the question please? I'm not sure how I would do this with junction points.